# MYSQL ONDUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ISSUE

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' statement to update column when duplicate primary key are already in table.
but even if table has duplicated primary key, it does not update column.

below is  'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' statement.
is there somthing wrong?

```
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE authenticated = authenticated
                  and notAuthenticated = notAuthenticated
                  and stoped = stoped
                  and deleted = deleted
                  and updatedDate = now()
```

;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `VALUES(Column)` and replace all this `AND` with comma `,`:

```
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE authenticated = VALUES(authenticated),
                  notAuthenticated = VALUES(notAuthenticated),
                  stoped = VALUES(stoped),
                  deleted = VALUES(deleted),
                  updatedDate = now()
```

Comment: No problem mate, but I think you accepted the wrong answer @happenask :)

Comment: sorry, i fix it now

Answer (score 1):

Don't use AND, but use commas:

```
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
              authenticated = VALUES(authenticated),
              notAuthenticated = VALUES(notAuthenticated),
              stoped = VALUES(stoped),
              deleted = VALUES(deleted),
              updatedDate = now()
```

Comment: Did you just copy my answer?

Comment: Sorry sagi, I see you were first.
There is a small error in yours, by the way.